# Testing react-contenteditable with react testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

How to test this component: https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable? How to mimic user action in test environment? I've tried following:

```
// The given element does not have a value setter
fireEvent.change(sourceContent, {
  target: { value: "New content text" }
});

// This doesn't emit onChange Changes text content but onChange is not fired.
fireEvent.change(sourceContent, {
  target: { textContent: "New content text" }
});

// This doesn't emit onChange. Changes inner html but onChange is not fired.
fireEvent.change(sourceContent, {
  target: { innerHTML: "New content text" }
});
```

All of the above are failed tests. I thought that if I change innerHTML then function provided in `onChange` will be fired. This is sample project with this problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-bush-m42hw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/442 fixed, it's now possible with [userEvent](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro/):

```
const element = screen.getByTestId("myEditableElement");
await userEvent.click(element);
await userEvent.keyboard("abc");
expect(element.textContent).toBe("abc");
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like for testing input you should use `fireEvent.input`. So following:

```
// This doesn't emit onChange. Changes inner html but onChange is not fired.
fireEvent.change(sourceContent, {
  target: { innerHTML: "New content text" }
});
```

Will be good way to mimic user input.

Comment: fireEvent.input? or fireEvent.change?

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible to simulate events on `contenteditable` with `testing-react-library`, or any testing library that uses `js-dom`, because of a limitation on `js-dom` itself.

See the discussion [here](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/pull/235) and [here](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1670).

The solution would be to use `puppeteer` or another method that uses a real browser for rendering.

Answer (score 4):

As Paul says on Github [here](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/pull/235#issuecomment-601078339): "Unfortunately, at the moment this feature has not been added to JSDOM, but there are people building features in React that require testing `ContentEditable`, and currently this is not possible with RTL as things currently stand, so far as I can tell."

But one way that works is fire the blur event and input is changed. See below:

```
fireEvent.blur(NameField, {target: {textContent: 'edited-text'}});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to focus on the element using userEvent.tab() then use userEvent.keyboard() to write on the contenteditable element like this example below:

```
await step(
    'Should have the value "Hello ahmnouira, how are you?"',
    async () => {
      userEvent.tab(editor)
      // use delay to simulate typings.
      await userEvent.keyboard(`Hello ahmnouira, how are you?`, {
        delay: 100,
      })
      expect(editor.textContent).toBe('Hello ahmnouira, how are you?')
    }
  )
```