# onChange is not called when used with userEvent.type from React testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, jsdom, slate

I am using RTL with Jest to test a Slate editor. I use .type to emulate a user typing into the editor and expect that Slate's onChange will be called. However, this does not happen.

Here's my editor code

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { createEditor } from "slate";
import { Slate, Editable, withReact } from "slate-react";

const initialValue = [
  {
    type: "paragraph",
    children: [{ text: "Foo" }]
  }
];

export default function Editor({ onChange }) {
  const [editor] = useState(() => withReact(createEditor()));
  return (
    <Slate onChange={onChange} editor={editor} value={initialValue}>
      <Editable data-testid="my_editor" />
    </Slate>
  );
}
```

Here's my test code:

```js
import React from "react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import Editor from "../editor";

test("test", async () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup();
  const onChange = jest.fn();
  render(<Editor onChange={onChange} />);

  expect(screen.getByTestId("my_editor")).toHaveTextContent("Foo");

  user.type(screen.getByTestId("my_editor"), " some more text");

  // I also tried this but did not work...
  // user.click(screen.getByTestId("my_editor"));
  // user.keyboard("bar");

  // also this did not work...
  // fireEvent.change(screen.getByTestId("my_editor"), {
  //   target: { innerHTML: "<p>hello world</p>" }
  // });

  // or this...
  // fireEvent.blur(screen.getByTestId("my_editor"), {
  //   target: { innerHTML: "<p>hello world</p>" }
  // });

  expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

If it's easier I have also created a minimal reproduction [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/slate-rtl-j10di3?file=/src/__tests__/index.js).

To reproduce the behavior:

- Go to 'tests/index.js'
- Run the tests
- There is an assertion that the onChange was called but it fails

I expected that the onChange will be called. This behavior only happens when tests are ran. In a normal browser onChange is indeed called.

Comment: My bad, i tried to run the test in CodeSandbox but it was showing passing and it is now not due to previously having the bad data. Removing my answer until i have more info

Comment: One thing i can tell that there is no contentedible with slate-react, so your `user.type` isn't going to work, and is the cause of why `onChange` is not being called. I'd suggest that you do a assertion of the input field that the input value is really being updated after the `user.type` so you get more context on whats been happening behind the scene.

Comment: Seems like you have asked this in official repo a while back https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/issues/5425

Comment: Yeah indeed I did ask it a while ago but got no reply! 

Regarding your comment yes the value is indeed changed but my problem is that the onChange is not called. The thing is that my component relies on onChange to be called so that it updates its parent. So even though the actual editor value is changed the parent will never find out.

Comment: No the value is not changed after the `user.type`, you can assert it by adding `expect(screen.getByTestId("my_editor")).toHaveTextContent("Foo some more text");` after your `user.type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with `contenteditable` which is what slate uses.

Essentially the issue lies with `js-dom` itself and testing libraries that use `js-dom` will all run into this issue.

Look at the discussion and links here [Testing react-contenteditable with react testing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60495903/testing-react-contenteditable-with-react-testing-library)

Even the fix that works for `testing-library` that uses `UserEvents` is able to have the change reflected but doesn't trigger the `onChange` events.

On a fork of your code I have added the UserEvent to modify the editor and also added a test that checks for the updated output, which passes.
However, the onChange test still fails.

Also, UserEvents v14.x.x is giving some [trouble](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/1150), so I have used v13.5 in my example
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/slate-rtl-forked-dv8zcm?file=/src/__tests__/index.js)

So due to the limitations of the `js-dom`, it will be impossible to have a workable test for this. Instead, it is recommended to use other libraries such as `puppeteer`.